# Return HTTP code 200 from Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to use this code to receive http link with values:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
public String handleNotifications(@RequestParam("notification") String itemid) {
    // parse here the values
    return "result successful result";
}
```

How I can return http code `200` - successful response?

And also for example if there is a code exception into code processing how can I return error `404`?

Comment: Check [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735084/return-http-code-200-from-spring-rest-api/51735123#51735123) updated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by annotating your method with [`@ResponseStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) using [`HttpStatus.OK`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#OK) (However it should be `200` by default), like this:

*Some controller*

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String handleNotifications(@RequestParam("notification") String itemid) throws MyException {
    if(someCondition) {
       throw new MyException("some message");
    }
    // parse here the values
    return "result successful result";
}
```

Now, in order to return a custom code when handling a specific exception you can create a whole separate controller for doing this (you can do it in the same controller, though) which extends from [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) and is annotated with [`@RestControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html) and it must have a method for handling that specific exception as shown below:

*Exception handling controller*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyException(MyException ex, WebRequest req) {
        Object resBody = "some message";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, resBody, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, req);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do know if there is a exception into the method code how I can return error status code?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. You mean if there is an exception, how to modify the response status? Please edit the question in order to be clearer.

Comment: Note that Boot handles the exception translation by default; you throw the annotated exception and it Just Works.

Comment: IMO - returning a primitive like String and letting spring handle creating the ReponseEntity implcitly is cleaner than crafting ResponseEntity oneself...

Comment: How to implement all that suggested. Can you write en example. for  class MyException.

Comment: @Nikzin I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean an example of a `MyException` class implementation? If so, it's just a regular java class extending one of the java exception classes, such as `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 35):

If you are using spring:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
public ResponseEntity handleNotifications(@RequestParam("notification") String itemid) {
    // parse here the values
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build(); 
    //OR ResponseEntity.ok("body goes here");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you use `@RestController` it should return 200 by default.

But anyway, you can set a particular response status by `@ResponseStatus` annotation (even if the methods returns `void`) or you can return a custom response by `ResponseEntity`.

*EDIT: added error handling*

For error handling, you can return a particular response entity:

```
 return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
            .body("some body ");
```

or you can use `@ExceptionHandler`:

```
   @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleError(Exception ex) {
        // TODO: log exception
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(
 @RequestParam("notification") String itemid) {
   // parse here the values
   return new ResponseEntity<>("result successful result", 
   HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I get Cannot infer type arguments for ResponseEntity<>

Comment: edited the original answer, what exactly are you looking for?